# Android-Volley: TimeOutError when trying to connect from a real device

Tags: android, laravel-5, xampp, android-volley

For an example, I am unable to make my device fetch data from my local server, even thought I've searched for similar questions, and tried everything.

This is my code in Laravel:

web.php:

```
   Route::get('/test', function()
{ return Subject::all(); });
```

Subject.php:

```
class Subject extends Model
{
    protected $table='subjects';
    protected $primary_key='subjectid'; 

    public $timestamps=false;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Button.OnClickListener {

Button btn;
TextView textview;
String url = "http://192.168.1.*:80/test";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    switch(view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btn:

            final RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

            StringRequest string = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                        textview.setText(response);
                        Log.d("response", response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "An error has ocurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    request.stop();
                }
            }
            );

            request.add(string);

            break;
    }
}
```

}

And this is the error:

> W/System.err: com.android.volley.TimeoutError
>   W/System.err: at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:169)
>   W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:120)
>   W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:87)

Both my device and my laptop are connected to the same WLAN; I've added a rule for Ports 80 and 443 (TCP, I imagine) - I tried disabling my firewall and alas, it worked and my string was fetched! Nevertheless, that's risky and an awful practice...
If possible, I would like to know the solution to this issue, what else do I need to configure? Thank you!

Comment: is internet permission taken ??

Comment: Forgot to mention that yes, it is declared in the manifest. Also, I'm using API 19.

Comment: some errors on server, response not coming from server, check url or server side code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code in your volley request before request.add(string) to change timeout duration.

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        5000, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Comment: The time limit seemed to work and solve my issue, thanks a lot!